# JQuery Multidimensional Array or Object Or Other Approach?

Tags: jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

Basically, what I have is a questionnaire that is very dynamic & data-driven in nature...

for each question i can have a 
    question number, 
    0 or more options of radio buttons, 
    0 or more options of check boxes,
    then for each option radio button i will have a 
      option id, 
      value
    and for each option check box i will have a
      option id, 
      value
    and for each option that is a textarea i will have a
      option id, 
      value
    If I have no options I can have a yes no radio button group, which would have a
      question id, 
      value
    If I have no options I can also have a textarea, which would have a
      question id, 
      value

I have everything rendering the way I want and my change and click events in jquery are firing when I expect them to...

Problem In my JQuery at the moment is I am trying to ferret out a way to save all these question answers as they are answered and if they are changed update or replace what I had previously stored...

Once the user is done with the answers, and edits as applicable, I will post the jquery/json to my controller in my mvc3 based solution; if I can get my what kind of Jquery structure I need to do this figured out I am good to go...

The approach to the structure required to do this in JQuery is giving me a headache...

at the moment I am thinking of something along the lines of the following...

```
   var $ArrayToPost = [];

    var $questionare =
    {
        Questions: {
            QuestionNumber: null,
            Options: [],
            YesNo: [],
            TextArea: []
        }
    };

    $('input.Questionare, textarea.Questionare').live({
      click: function (e) {
      ...rest omitted for brevity...
      $questionare.Questions.QuestionNumber = $QuestionNbr;
      $questionare.Questions.Options.push($CheckBox);

      $ArrayToPost.push($questionare);

      ...rest omitted for brevity...
      change : function (e) {
      ...rest omitted for brevity...
    });
```

problem I have with this approach is whenever a check box, radio button is clicked or the value is changed in a text area I would have to figure out what I already added to the structure for the applicable question number and either update whatever is applicable or just replace what is applicable...

I think I am over complicating this and would certainty like a more elegant approach...

thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** Still have not come up with a way to get this going, hope somebody can get me going in the right direction...

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similiar to this. 
If you are doing it as an app, and need to leave that page...perhaps look at saving the answers in cookies. I'd suggest a local database, but it appears the local databases are up in the air at the moment, going forward.

If you are staying on the same page, then javascript variables or javascript window variables are a thought.  Then, on the onchange event, look at the previously saved value to see if the value has changed to the correct answer, etc.

If you are doing it as a webpage instead of an app, you could use php or something server side to store the object or array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need two structures for this. The first will hold all of the questions and options while the second holds the answers. Since your question "template" will be the same for all participants of the survey, you can pass that JS object around in a JSON format and use it any time you need to display question and answer combinations.

The second structure you'd use would be only for retaining answers before POSTing them back to the server. See my examples below:

First, the object for holding the actual questionnaire:

```
var questionnaire = {
    Questions : [
        {
            number: 1,
            type: 'Radio'
            options: ['Choice 1', 'Choice 2', 'Choice 3']
        }
    ]
};
```

And repeat the object within "Questions:" for each question. Specify a type and then use your jQuery code to create the appropriate radio, checkbox, textarea, etc elements. Obviously in some cases the "options" array isn't needed (e.g. textarea).

For storing answers, it's even easier. Just build an array and go from there.

```
var answers = [

];

function recordAnswer(qNum, answer) {
    answers[qNum] = answer;
}
```

Each time an answer is recorded (you can use the "onchange" event), call recordAnswer() and pass in the question number and the supplied answer. Any question that the user updates will automatically override the previous answer.

When you're ready to POST your data, just convert the object to JSON, and pass through the appropriate jQuery Ajax method.

On the other hand, if you need to POST everything (including the question template), just loop through the available questions and look for an element in the answers array with the same number as the current question, and record the answer within that first object template. Then POST to server.

That's a couple ways of doing it. Hope one of them works for you :)

Comment: I am not quite following you ... all my questions are dynamic and I can have yes no radio button groups, as well as radio button lists and checkbox lists and textareas for each question and I can have n number of pageable questions displayed at any given time... not much I can define statically...

Comment: in jquery code I can see how to add each individual array of 0 or more items for an applicable question... but i do not see how to proceed when say I have a list of check boxes and 0 or more text areas for example for the same question; when the click and change events for each are fired separately... so say the change event fires and a checkbox is selected & added with its values & question number to the in process array that I want to post... then some text is keyed into a text box that is part of the same question... if i add the same question number and current values I will lose info.

Comment: My approach will still work for you. When recording your answers just address your array like this: answers[qNum]['textarea'] = answer;

So, your data structure for each question is like this: answer = { 0: { textarea: "", radio: ""} } and so forth. You may need to set up the structure as you read in your questionnaire, but this should be trivial.